# Merge N amount of DataTables while summing one of the columns

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have N amount of DataTables, I need to merge them into one Datatable, while also summing the "value" column which all tables have. Example below.

[image]

Please note: It can be any amount of tables to be merged, also the fields are dynamic meaning its not necessary only "Year" is there, it can be anything but the "Value" column will always be there, and the tables will have same columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my quick&dirty solution would probably look like this...

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        //make dummy data
        List<DataTable> dts = new List<DataTable>();

        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            var dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("foo", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("bar", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("baz", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(int));

            for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(rnd.Next(1, 5), rnd.Next(1, 5), rnd.Next(1, 5), rnd.Next(1, 2000));
            }
            dts.Add(dt);
        }

        //dummy data complete

        // the grouping step
        var intermediateResult = dts.SelectMany(x => x.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()).GroupBy(x => x, new NotValueColumnComparer()).Select(x => new { grp = x.Key, sum = x.Sum(y => y.Field<int>("Value")) });


        // transform back into a data tabe
        var result = new DataTable();

        foreach (var col in dts.First().Columns.Cast<DataColumn>())
        {
            result.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName);
        }

        foreach (var item in intermediateResult)
        {
            var row = result.NewRow();

            foreach (var grpField in item.grp.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Where(x => x.ColumnName != "Value"))
            {
                row[grpField.ColumnName] = item.grp[grpField.ColumnName];
            }
            row["Value"] = item.sum;

            result.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        //transform end

    }

    //the class that does the trick
    public class NotValueColumnComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataRow>
    {
        //compare all columns but the Value column
        public bool Equals(DataRow x, DataRow y)
        {
            foreach (var col in x.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>())
            {
                if (col.ColumnName != "Value")
                    if (x[col.ColumnName] != y[col.ColumnName])
                        return false;
            }
            return true;
        }


        //as a simple hash code ... just xor the values hash codes
        public int GetHashCode(DataRow obj)
        {
            int res = 0;
            foreach (var col in obj.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>())
            {
                if (col.ColumnName != "Value")
                    res ^= obj[col].GetHashCode();
            }
            return res;
        }
    }
}
```

if you are not afraid of additional libraries, you might want to have a look ad dynamic LINQ ...